# Annotation position is not updated as the series scrolls

Tags: java, teechart

I am using Annotation and AnnotationCallout to create labels on a series. But the problem I have is that their positions are not updating as new data is added to the chart. The series scrolls, but the Annotation / AnnotationCallout stay in the same place.

I set the Annotation and AnnotationCallout with the following code:

```
Anno.setLeft(aSeries.calcXPos(iIndex)-51);
Anno.setTop(aSeries.calcYPos(iIndex)+100);

Callout.setXPosition(aSeries.calcXPos(iIndex));
Callout.setYPosition(aSeries.calcYPos(iIndex));
```

Is there a way to attach them to point on a series or am I using the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations are positioned either on pixel positions or relative positions on the chart depending on how you define the `Scaling` property.

That's how `Annotation` works. So once you have defined the position of the annotation it sticks there.

If you want labels sticked on the points, look at `Series.Marks`.

When you add points to the series you can add a label text like:

> AddXY(xPos,yPos,'Hello',clGreen);

Set `Series.Marks.Visible := True` to show the mark labels. To customize the label text on the fly, look at the event `TChartSeries.OnGetMarkText`.

Explore all `Series.Marks` properties to customize the look to your preference.

Update :

In order to hide some marks on your series data, set the label text to empty string during the `OnGetMarkText` event.

An example how to use `OnGetMarkText`:

```
...
Series1.OnGetMarkText := Self.Series1GetMarkText;  // Define the OnGetMarkText event
...

procedure TMyForm.Series1GetMarkText(Sender: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer; var MarkText: string);
begin
  if ValueIndex=3 then  // Just an example how to set the selection criteria 
    MarkText := 'Hello'
  else
    MarkText := '';
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. SeriesMarks is what I was looking for. Its working, except that all of the points on the series have marks with their y values. How do I prevent this?

Comment: If I set all marks to "" then the y value still appears. Here is my code:

SeriesMarks sMarks_Chart1_Line2 = new SeriesMarks(Chart1_Line2);
sMarks_Chart1_Line2.setVisible(true);
sMarks_Chart1_Line2.getPen().setColor(Color.RED);  
  
Chart1_Line2.setMarks(sMarks_Chart1_Line2);
Chart1_Line2.getMarks().setVisible(true);

Chart1_Line2.add(new com.steema.teechart.DateTime(new DateTime(tsDateTime).getMillis()), dStart_value, "");

Comment: Hmm, try activating the `OnGetMarkText` instead. The latest documentation for TeeChart (in XE2) says : "This event notifies the user that a Mark Text String must be supplied. MarkText string contains the default text representation. You can alter MarkText for the Series to paint a customized mark, or set it to empty to hide the specific mark."

Comment: @user1254689 you may need to set Marks.Style as well, for example: Series1.Marks.Style:=smsLabel

Comment: I am completely stumped. How do I access OnGetMarkText in Java? If its through addSeriesPaintListener; how do I identify this event?

Comment: Ok, not your fault, the question is tagged with Delphi. I think @NarcísCalvet may provide some more help since my Java knowledge for TeeChart is limited.

Comment: Hello,

Find an example of MarkTextResolver's usage here: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=6757&start=0